# Windows Batch File - CLS command not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

Running on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit [Version 10.0.17763.1637];

I'm writing a simple batch file to show active processes:

```
cls
echo.
echo Showing all processes similar to %1*
tasklist /FO table /FI "IMAGENAME eq %1*"|more
```

However, I see that the screen is not being cleared as the script is launched (CLS works fine if I invoke it manually from my Command Line).

I know it's actually a quite silly issue, I'm just curious to know why that hppens and if there's any workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Massimo

Comment: Is this the entire script, or is there more before this snippet? If `cls` is actually the first line, then my first thought is that you've saved the file with some encoding that isn't ANSI or UTF-8 and that the BOM is causing `cls` to be read as something different.

Comment: First of all, is this really all of your batch file content? You have no `echo off`, no `setlocal` etc. The main questions I'd like to ask is what is the file encoding of your script, _(`ANSI`, `UTF-8`, `UTF-8 BOM`, `UTF-16 LE` etc)_, and what type of line endings is it using, _(`CRLF`, `LF` ,`CR`)_. Sometimes just posting the content, or some of it, does not give us all of the information we need. Please ensure that your batch file is written using ANSI encoding with CRLF line endings.

Comment: First line of my script is @echo off, then come the posted ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked your script and cls works perfect(except for it isn't showing active processes) you just need to add `@echo off`and also validate encoding as `ANSI` if it isn't,if you want command line without prompt,here it is:

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo Showing all processes similar to %1*
tasklist
rem tasklist /FO table /FI "IMAGENAME eq %1*"|more
```

Comment: `tasklist /FO table /FI "IMAGENAME eq %1*"|more` is a perfectly working command, given that `%1` is non empty and not doublequoted, _(although I'm not really sure why piping it to `more` is required)_. I'd therefore like to tell you that it very likely does meet the criteria for tasklist.

Comment: @Compo then i would like to know why am i getting `INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.`

Comment: Perhaps what you're using as `%1` is not matching any image names! Open a Command Prompt window, type `tasklist /FO table /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe*"|more` as if `%1` was received as `cmd.exe`. Then do the same using `tasklist /FO table /FI "IMAGENAME eq c*"|more`, as if `c` was received as the first argument.

Comment: @Compo Oh Thank-you,now i get it. its a filter to get specific processes.but if he wanted all the active processes,then `tasklist` would have given his results.and also if i want a wildcard for all characters(i.e from a to z) how would i do that

Comment: Justaus3r, the question is only about the `cls` command, when used in the script not working as expected. It isn't your question, so I'm wondering why, you've started asking me a question unrelated to the issue reported. If you have a question, you'd like assistance with, feel free to submit your question in the normal manner.

Comment: @Compo oh-nothin i was just curious as i am not  an ideal batch programmer

Comment: The first line is @cls, then the other posted come. The script works just fine in my computer, except from the fact that the screen is not cleared as I wish (not a big issue, anyway).  Usually I call this script by passing the name of an application as an argument, i.e. myscript.bat firefox, and it correctly lists all the active instances of the executable.  Piping to More is in case the output list gets very long.

Comment: Exactly ANSI solved for me. echo string > file generates  UTF-... file